Borges comment about the Qurʾān and related
The renowned South American writer, Borges, gave a series of conferences on diverse topics called Siete Noches (Seven nights), where we can read/hear the following (among many other scattered comments on the subject).

For the ulema, the doctors of Muslim law, the  Qurʾān is not a
book like the others. It is a book ―this is incredible, but this is how it
is― previous to the Arabic language, so one may not study it
historically or philologically, because it is previous  to the Arabs, previous
to its/their language, and previous to the universe. Nor even do
they admit that the Qurʾān be a work of God; it is something more
intimate and mysterious. The Qurʾān, for the orthodox Muslims, is an
attribute of God, like His rage, His mercy, or His justice. The Qurʾān itself
speaks of a mysterious book, the mother of the book, the celestial archetype of the Qurʾān. It is in heaven and is worshiped by the angels.

(my own literal translation).
I am interested in the second part of the paragraph where he says that the Qurʾān is considered an attribute of God. Does that exist in any school of Islamic mysticism? If so, which ones and what else has been said along those lines.

I'm not sure if your exact question has been covered here so leaving a comment instead of a dupe-vote, but the topic has come up many times on the site. Try searching for "uncreated".
